# How to access individual values ​of a list item in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I'm not able to assign the first item value of a list to a turtle variable. For example? I have list3 that has 1 item, that is:
list3: [[5 2]]

I would like the first value of list 3 item 0 to be assigned to reproduction (ie 5) and the second value of list 3 item 0 to be assigned to metabolism (ie 2).

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

```
globals [ ValidHabsItem ValidHabs ItemList3 ]

turtles-own [ profiles-habitat metabolism reproduction ]

to setup
  let list1 ( list 2  )
  let list2 ( list 5 )
  let list3 ( reduce sentence ( map [ i -> map [ j -> list j i ] list2 ] list1 ) ) 
  print ( word "list3: " list3 )
  let n0 count turtles 
  let s length list3 * 10


  while [ n0 < s ]
  [
    let c count patches 
    if c = 0 [ stop ]
    ask one-of patches
    [
      sprout 1
      [
        set profiles-habitat item ValidHabsItem ValidHabs
        set reproduction item ItemList3 list3 ;; list3: [[5 2]];; value 5
        set metabolism item ItemList3 list3   ;; list3: [[5 2]];; value 2   
      ]     
    ]
  ]
set n0 count turtles
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily understand how to do this by playing in the Command Center and seeing how NetLogo responds to your calls to the list.

Just create a global variable in the Code tab, as `globals [my-list]`, and then follow my statements in the Command Center:

```
observer> set my-list [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
observer> print my-list
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
```

So here we just created a list whose items are other lists.

Therefore, we have:

```
observer> print first my-list
[1 2 3]
observer> print last my-list
[7 8 9]
observer> print item 1 my-list
[4 5 6]
```

This means that now, for NetLogo, the whole `first my-list` statement is equal to `[1 2 3]`; in other words, it is a list containing those numbers. So you can treat `first my-list` as any other list. For example, if you want to extract the second item from that list, you will simply do:

```
observer> print item 1 (first my-list)
2
```

The parentheses there are optional: they are useful to make the statement more readable to humans, reminding us that the whole `first my-list` is a list from which we are extracting the second item (i.e. the item with index 1). However, NetLogo does not really need that:

```
observer> print item 1 first my-list
2
```

Now you should be able to easily solve your problem, because your case is easier than this: your `list3`, which in your example is `[[5 2]]`, only has one item in it. This means that `first list3` is equal to `last list3` which is equal to `item 0 list3`, all of them being `[5 2]`.

So there you can do:

```
set reproduction first (first list3)
set metabolism last (first list3)
```

In general, you can apply this mechanisms to how many levels of nesting you wish.

For example:

```
observer> set my-list [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]]]
observer> print my-list
[[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]]]
observer> print first my-list
[[1 2] [3 4]]
observer> print last (first my-list)
[3 4]
observer> print first (last (first my-list))
3
```

---

PS:
Note that, in your `while` loop, you need to include `set n0 count turtles` within the command block (as in *while [condition] [commands]*).
The way you have it now, `set n0 count turtles` is outside the command block of the loop and this means that the loop will go on forever, because it will never get to the point where `n0` is updated and so `n0 < s` will always evaluate as true.

Also, note that saying

```
let c count patches 
if c = 0 [ stop ]
```

makes no sense in NetLogo: every model will always have at least one patch, so you will never get to the point of having no patches.
Maybe you wanted to say something like `if (count patches with [not any? turtles-here] = 0) [stop]`? Just guessing, but here we are going off-topic

Comment: thanks Matteo! Resolved